# fluxbox tabbed windows and fine-grained application window control in XFCE

Tags: xfce, fluxbox

Is there anything like window tabbing feature from fluxbox window manager in xfce?

Also, can one configure the size, position and similar properties of any given application window in xfce (I am looking for the analogue of .fluxbox/apps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Xfce FAQ the answer is no - the position and a size will be saved only when the application supports it. https://wiki.xfce.org/faq#window_manager

The one possibility for windows placement I'm aware of is similar to that used in Windows 7 <= OS - one can drag a window to the side or a corner of the screen in order to make it occupy a half or a quarter of it.

However if You use some programs on a regular manner, You can save Your session, so on each login, applications will be at the same positions, as during logout.

Comment: Is it possible to save multiple session and name them?

Comment: @MaliRemorker You can go to `Settings`->`Session and Startup`. On a Tab `General` You should choose an option `Display chooser on login` and possibly `Automatically save session on logout`. Under a `Session` tab You can also manually save a session with those programs running, You want to start automatically. On log in a prompt window will appear, where You will be able to choose a session by double click on it, or to create a new session (but you will need to remember to save it later, if you did not choose the automatic save).